# Calling in multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

still quite new to jQuery / Javascript and am struggling a little.

I have created an attribute called **catno** that I have assigned to several links.  Then I want all instances inside **banner-1** to be called into another link separated by a comma.  i.e

```
<a href="1290311655,1337929192,1374407572,1337930498,1353983749," class="buy-outfit">New Link</a>
```

I'm just struggling in making this happen.  The code I have right now only returns the first catno.

Any help would be great!

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BHXp9/)**

```
<div id="banner-1>
<a href="" catno="1290311655" class="add-catno" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" catno="1337929192" class="add-catno" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" catno="1374407572" class="add-catno" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" catno="1337930498" class="add-catno" alt="" title=""></a>
<a href="" catno="1353983749" class="add-catno" alt="" title=""></a>

<a href="" class="new-link">New Link</a>
</div>

$sd('.buy-outfit').attr('href', function() {
return $sd("#banner-1 .add-catno").attr('catno') + ',';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/A7LWf/)

```
var arr_catno = $("#banner-1 a").map(function () {  //create array using .map
    return $(this).attr('catno'); // add element attribute catno to array 
}).get().join(); //use .join() to get comma separated string of array 
$('.new-link').attr('href', arr_catno); //assign it to href
```

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

---

Updated after OP's Comment

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/A7LWf/3)

```
$('[id^=banner-] .new-link').attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('a').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('catno');
    }).get().join();
});
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

`[id^=banner-]` --> select all the elements with id starting with `banner-`

Comment: Thanks!!  If I wanted to go ahead and create a #banner-2/3/4/5.  How would I do this without adding the code in x amount of times?  Fiddled it here - http://jsfiddle.net/A7LWf/2/  

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to produce an array of catnos and them `join` them into a string.

```
$('.new-link').attr('href', function() {
  return $.map($(".add-catno"), function (el) {
    return $(el).data('catno');
  }).join(',');
});
```

Note in the example that I've changed the catnos attributes to `data` attributes. Using `data` is considered good practice for when you want to add arbitrary data to your HTML.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ysD7T/)